# Including length when making a networkx network from a geodataframe

Tags: python, geopandas, network, networkx, dijkstra

I'm a noob when it comes to networkx module. I have a line feature as a geodataframe that looks like this:

[image: figure1]

Using momepy, I can convert this geodataframe to a network on network x:

```py
G = momepy.gdf_to_nx(my_line, approach="primal",length='mm_len')
```

This converts the geodataframe to a network that looks like this, with the blue points as the nodes created by momepy: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Smb9.png

My aim is to find the pair of nodes that are furthest away from one another.

I can do this by this code:

```
apl = dict(nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path(G))
bpl = [tuple((v, s, k)) for s, d in apl.items() for k, v in d.items() if v == max(d.values())]
bpl.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0], reverse=False) 
length, start, fin = bpl[0]
```

However this works out the distances based on how many nodes the path goes through, not the actual length of the path. so returning 'length' just gets a list of coordinates. However I have no idea how to store the length of the path in the network. I want the data of the graph to be something like this:

[image: figure1]

So that when I run the Dijkstra it will return the top left node and the bottom node and say the distance between them is 21m, this is the longest. Any ideas?

Comment: It is a pure [network](https://networkx.org/) problem and not a geospatial problem. You need to use [all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length.html)

Comment: but how do I add a length feature to the graph itself? Do I define it as a weight? Because as I said if I run dijkstra it returns a list of coordinates, not a length. When you create a networkx graph manually with add_edges_from etc. you can add in attributes  but I can't see an option for that when doing momepy.gdf_to_nx

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geometry and the properties of the GeoDataFrame are still present in the graph, you can see them in using `data=True` (and the length is 'mm_len') (see [How to calculate edge length in Networkx](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/213431/2581))

With one of my shapefile

```
G = momepy.gdf_to_nx(df, approach="primal",length='mm_len')
G.edges()
MultiEdgeDataView([((166362.43059958215, 116180.34149187146), (166547.61246095796, 117903.66656916466)), ((165402.50829775655, 117317.8872117514), (166925.53462703104, 116758.56240596325)), ((165829.56034541913, 116044.28951208515), (166691.22288406573, 117121.3676853934)), ((165500.76806093557, 117627.78338793133), (165549.89794252507, 116887.0559424281))])
# but
G.edges(data=True)
MultiEdgeDataView([((166362.43059958215, 116180.34149187146), (166547.61246095796, 117903.66656916466), {'geometry': <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x1a352982e8>, 'mm_len': 2966.689088302621}), ((165402.50829775655, 117317.8872117514), (166925.53462703104, 116758.56240596325), {'geometry': <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x1a352988d0>, 'mm_len': 1622.6709776373805}), ((165829.56034541913, 116044.28951208515), (166691.22288406573, 117121.3676853934), {'geometry': <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x1a35298390>, 'mm_len': 1379.3330714239971}), ((165500.76806093557, 117627.78338793133), (165549.89794252507, 116887.0559424281), {'geometry': <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x1a35298828>, 'mm_len': 883.3292113713896})]
```

First edge of the graph:

```
first = list(G.edges(data=True))[0]
```

The two first elements of the resulting list are the nodes coordinates and the third is a is a dictionary

```
print(first[2]['mm_len'])
2966.689088302621
```

Therefore you can use

```
list(nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(G,weight='mm_len'))
```

For the first path

```
list(nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(G,weight='mm_len'))[0]
((166362.43059958215, 116180.34149187146), {(166362.43059958215, 116180.34149187146): 0, (166547.61246095796, 117903.66656916466): 2966.689088302621})
 #and the length is
 l = [x for x in list(nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(G,weight='mm_len'))[1][1].values()]
 print(l[1])
 2966.689088302621
```